# Social events for Stack Overflow users

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, meetups

Do Stack Overflow users ever have some sort of social events where they can meet and talk in person?
If not, is there interest in such an event?  I thought it would be nice to meet people in real life.

I made a chat room for this question:
http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/60262/social-events-for-stack-overflow-users

Comment: @aaa: Take a look at my gravatar. Would *you* want to meet me in person? :)

Comment: @I miss well, I was arrested in bomb plot 10 years ago, so I am okay :-)

Comment: @aaa: What can I say to that? :) Off-topic, having just read your profile, how well does TTS work for code? (One of my greatest fears is one day not being able to type ... )

Comment: "`I thought it would be nice to meet people in real life.`" - In general or specifically SO users?

Comment: I have just created a chat room for this question. Why? To kind of play off of @Thomas Owen's geolocation thing -- maybe a meetups can be arranged there.

Comment: @I miss TTS  is okay, not as good as typing, but you can get by (actually make me better programmer I think, more time to think, less time to bang keyboard).
recent saw eeg headset, maybe I will give that try.

Comment: @Peter overflow users specifically, most of my friends do not care much for programming/technology at all

Comment: You know, I should have included the [chat link](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/60262/social-events-for-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 5):

Meet... in person? Without using a computer? *shudder*

There was a series of [Stack Overflow Dev Days](http://stackoverflow.carsonified.com/) in 2009*. but nothing planned so far for 2010.

*<sub>See also the [[devdays](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=devdays)] tag for stories from last year's events.</sub>

Comment: I take it you were joking about without computer.
Dev Days look awesome, but I was thinking more in terms of the afterparty part of conference :-)

Answer (score 4):

I would love to buy a drink for a number of Stack Overflow users, if they would come to the Rochester, New York area in the next 8 or so months...

You know, I wouldn't mind seeing more geo-location abilities, like finding users close to you to have meetups and discussions and what not face-to-face to exchange knowledge.

Comment: Some sort of geolocation feature would definitely be a lot of fun.

Comment: exactly my thoughts.  maybe website developers would go for such request?

Comment: I guess someone should make that a feature request or throw some web-app together :)

Comment: I'm too lazy to write this up as a feature request, but if someone makes one, I'll ad my 2 cents.

Answer (score 4):

April 6, 2011 will be World-Wide Stack Overflow MeetUp Day per [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/stack-overflow-meetups-april-6/). Organization of specific events is being left up to individual users.

Answer (score 3):

We [BBQ](http://tweakers.net/ext/f/oXtCi3jl0OODLD8CICOu3dPj/full.jpg) almost every saturday. If you're in, just come to 12.1207,-68.8583.

Comment: Now, that is extremely tempting. You happen to have a spare bedroom for me and my SCUBA gear?

Comment: niiiice.  kind of far from Iowa :-)