# Can we have an automatic link if a chat room has been created for a question?

Tags: feature-request, chat, hyperlinks

I came up with this idea when thinking about [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60262/social-events-for-stack-overflow-users). I made a chat room for it, as a convenience to other users who may be interested in doing local in-person meetups, as that seemed to be something the OP was interested in. (And heck, I'd find it interesting, too, to be honest.)

I had to go back later and add a comment with the chat link, because I rather embarrassingly forgot to mention the link when I created the room.

It seems to me that the UI should include some form of automatic link if someone has created a room off a question.

(Yes, I'm aware of the irony of the guy who was [vehemently against this feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48249/web-based-irc-for-the-trilogy/48250#48250) making a request to simplify its usage.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm all for this, but "the official" line is that we are still in beta and would like to give chat a few more weeks of polish while before looking at integrating.

While we are at it, I would like the chat link to show how many messages are in the chat room, live. (eg. chat(20)) and if you click on the chat link have it light box in a mini chat window so I don't have to visit another site.