# How to convert comments into chat rooms

Tags: discussion, comments, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create comment-spawned chatrooms for the post, not for the users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98926/create-comment-spawned-chatrooms-for-the-post-not-for-the-users)

**How can I convert the comments on a post into a chat discussion? And how can I add a user to a chat?**

May I convert the comments on other users' questions into chat messages? If yes, how can I do this?

There should be functionality for adding users to question-inspired chat rooms that ensures that the users commented on the original question or performed some other activty there. This would allow us to turn the chat part of the site into something like a social networking site.

Comment: I do not think converting the comments on "other" questions into a chat session would be a good idea (assuming you did not participate in the aforementioned comments). The comment authors will probably not understand what's going on, or wonder why you disrupted the comment flow since you were not part of the discussion in the first place. You will probably get a lot of flak from this either way.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi ,no you didnt understand my question ,i just want that to add the users who are alredy commented on that question or perform some activity.

Comment: Ah, so you only want to create a chat room with all the participants from a given question?

Comment: yeah,absolutely right..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is currently no automated way to do this, although there are requests for similar functionality, as pointed out in the comments.

For now, when you want this, you can:

- manually create a new chatroom with [this form](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/new)
- manually post links to each relevant comment from the comment list/thread (see [the chat FAQ entry for "oneboxing"](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#formatting)
- manually restrict the write access for the room to just the users who participated at the original question
- Note that that's write access *only*. Everyone will be able to come in and watch the conversation, but only people you authorize will be able to talk. Again, see [the chat FAQ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#room-users)
- The shortcut for this is selecting "Gallery" at room creation time.
- link to the new chatroom in a new comment(s), using @-notifications as needed to invite people to participate

That said, I do question why you want to do this at all. As Jeff said at the feature request post,

> Blessing the idea of per-question chatrooms would also strongly imply that we bless moving topical question content off to chat, when we *explicitly do not!*

(emphasis original)